# Join columns in list of pandas dfs with common name

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join

I have a list of pandas dfs, of the form

```
                    'lb'     'ub'
rxn.name_0       --- stuff here ---
rxn.name_1       --- stuff here ---
rxn.name_2       --- stuff here ---
   ...                  ...
rxn.name_n_1     --- stuff here ---
rxn.name_n       --- stuff here ---
```

and I would like to join each column `ub` for each of the dfs after the first in the the list `[df_0, df_1, df_2, ..., df_n_1, df_n]` to the first element `df_0`. All of the row names are the same, `rxn.name_0`, `rxn.name_1`, etc.

How would I go about doing this so that I get

```
                    'lb'     'ub0'     'ub1'     ...
rxn.name_0       ----------- stuff here ------------
rxn.name_1       ----------- stuff here ------------
    ...                         ...
rxn.name_n_1     ----------- stuff here ------------
rxn.name_n       ----------- stuff here ------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mix between `join` for the `lb` column and `concat` for the `ub`s columns can do the job. Here test data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(3)
l = [
    pd.DataFrame(
        {'lb':np.random.randint(100, size=5), 'ub':np.random.randint(100, size=5)}, 
        index=['rxn.name_'+str(i) for i in range(5)])
    for _ in range(3)
]
```

and you can get the wanted result with:

```
res = (
    l[0][['lb']]
      .join(pd.concat([_df[['ub']].add_suffix(str(i)) 
                       for i, _df in enumerate(l)], axis=1))
)
print(res)
#             lb  ub0  ub1  ub2
# rxn.name_0  24   21   93   60
# rxn.name_1   3   19   39    1
# rxn.name_2  56   74   14   51
# rxn.name_3  72   41   26   90
# rxn.name_4   0   10   81   69
```

or with just one `concat`, you can

```
res = pd.concat(
    [_df[['ub']].add_suffix(str(i)) 
     if i>0 else _df.rename(columns={'ub':'ub0'})  
     for i, _df in enumerate(l)],
    axis=1)
print(res)
```

Comment: Your answer looks very interesting but I am getting this error when I use the pd.concat option: KeyError: "None of [Index(['ub'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: @therickster it means that one of your dataframes does not have the `ub` column

Comment: thanks, I fixed it! I will keep this as the answer

Comment: However, I get ub0, ub2, ..., ub7 instead of ub0, ub1, ub2, ..., ub8

Comment: @therickster the numbers for the column's name comes from the `enumerate`  from your comment, I assume it is the second dataframe that does not have the `ub` column? and how did you fix it?

Comment: I had the wrong formatting, I was calling a different function that did not have the column 'ub'.

Another question I have is what would I include in the "j" if I am transforming this to a long format:

pd.wide_to_long(df, ["lb","ub"], i="id", j=???)

Comment: @therickster not sure what is id here, but in `wide_to_long`, the j is a name you decide. you can use any string. That said, as `lb` does not have any other character in its name, it won't work. you need to rename lb as well I think

Comment: ok, I figured out that stubnames = ['lb', 'ub'] and i = id. So j should be the number beside 'lb', 'ub', etc. from 0 to 8. How would I make j its own numerical index?

Comment: @therickster if you want to give a specific number then in the solution above, do `_df.rename(columns={'ub':'ub0', 'lb':'lbXX'})` and replace `XX` by any value. if you want 0, then replace `_df.rename(columns={'ub':'ub0'})` by `_df.add_suffix(str(i))`, should work. but I'm not sure the result would be interesting